# Creating temporary table without knowing the columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, temp-tables

How to create a temporary table in oracle without knowing the number and name of columns.

For example:

```
Select columnA,columnB,* into temp_table from tableA.
```

Here,tableA maynot be a simple tablename but maybe derived from many queries.

*How can this be achieved?Is there any alternative to this?*

Comment: What do you mean with temporary table? Do you need to create a table as a result of a query, without specifying all the columns?

Comment: By temporary table, i mean that i should be able to create a table for temporarily holding the data.And for that temporary table,i don't know the columns.

Comment: Creating so-called temporary tables on the fly is common anti-pattern for people who are new to Oracle but familiar with other databases such as SQL Server. There is very rarely any need to do this in Oracle. Better approaches depend on why you think you need such temporary tables, that is, how you intent to use the queried data. But they include: writing efficient SQL (always a good idea); result set caching; ref cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you have to first create a table, then insert into it. Or, create it directly (as in my example).

Note that I've created a "normal" table; if it were *temporary*, you could have chosen between a *global* or *private* (depending on database version you use).

For this discussion, I guess that it is just fine:

```
SQL> create table temp_table as
  2    select a.*
  3    from (select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename    --> this SELECT is your "tableA"
  4          from emp e join dept d
  5          on e.deptno = d.deptno
  6          where job = 'CLERK'
  7         ) a;

Table created.

SQL> select * from temp_table;

    DEPTNO DNAME                ENAME
---------- -------------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING           MILLER
        20 RESEARCH             SMITH
        20 RESEARCH             ADAMS
        30 SALES                JAMES

SQL>
```

Alternatively, create a view and work with it:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_temp as
  2          select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  3          from emp e join dept d
  4          on e.deptno = d.deptno
  5          where job = 'CLERK'
  6  ;

View created.

SQL> select * from v_temp;

    DEPTNO DNAME                ENAME
---------- -------------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING           MILLER
        20 RESEARCH             SMITH
        20 RESEARCH             ADAMS
        30 SALES                JAMES

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

This statement creates `temp_table` which contains all columns and data from `tableA` and two other empty columns, varchar and numeric.

```
create table temp_table as 
  select cast (null as varchar2(10)) columnA, 
         cast (null as number(6)) columnB, 
         tableA.* 
    from tableA
```

If you need only structure, no data, then add:

```
    where 1 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to have a temp table as you do not know columns, but you can think of dynamic SQL to create table depending on columns required during your process and then drop it again. From my point of view I think it is not a good design.

I can suggest to think on using collection with 'x' number of columns with datatype  as VARCHAR2. During transaction you can populate and process according to you need and it will also remain for that session.